# Button getting hided if validation fails --php css wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

field validation is from php(server side).

upload button is client side(ext and file size).

for both field only one save button.

My goal is to hide save button once submitted and show processing...

but if validation fails save button will be hided.

```
 <form id="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
 <input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__))?>"/>
 <?php /* NOTICE: here we storing id to determine will be item added or updated */ ?>
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $item['id'] ?>"/>
 <div class="metabox-holder" id="poststuff">
 <div id="post-body">
 <div id="post-body-content">
 <?php /* And here we call our custom meta box */ ?>
 <?php do_meta_boxes('person', 'normal', $item); ?>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Save', 'custom_table_example')?>" id="submit" class="button-primary" name="submit" onclick="$('#submit').hide(); $('#submit1').show();" / >
 <input type="submit1" name="submit1" id="submit1" class="button-primary" value="PROCESSING...." style="display:none;   >           
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
console.log("plugin script loaded1");
$('#submit').click( function() {
$("#submit").hide();
$("#submit1").show();
});
});
```

Comment: It's because you need to return some data so that you can compare that whether the validation succeeded or failed so then in order to hide and show the button..!

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai button change is working but if validation fails only processing comes but save won't

Comment: cuz you are doing it very simply by just using click function and just simply hiding the save button and showing processing button simply with no futher logic at all..you need to make your code complex with the use of ajax..!

Comment: Share your full form code and also your form posting link file code..!

Comment: @Umair Shah Yousafzai   i have updated  my code....for reference :

Comment: http://mac-blog.org.ua/wordpress-custom-database-table-example-full/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118709/discussion-between-jmr-and-umair-shah-yousafzai).